# Extjs ReferenceError (function in plugged file is not defined)

Tags: function, extjs, referenceerror

i plug some utility files to the main application.
But on function *Flang()* from there is not referenced: web sniffer in console issues: 
**ReferenceError: FLang is not defined**

**index.html:**

```
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="application.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js" ></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lang.js" ></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/directories/assortment.js" ></script>

<title id="page-title">Main Application v.2.0</title>
    ...
```

**lang.js:**

```
...
function FLang(str){ 

 if (ComboBoxLang.getValue()=='en')
   return str;
 else if (ComboBoxLang.getValue()=='ru')
   return FappLangRu(str);
 else  
   return str;  
 };
```

In the network inspector i see this file *lang.js* loaded, yet still *this function is not defined*:
at application.js (last line in this snippet):

**application.js:**

```
 Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../app/extjs/examples/ux');
 Ext.require([
   'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
    'Ext.ux.grid.*', 
]);



Ext.ns("appMain");

...


appMain.NorthRegion = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {       
region: 'north',
xtype: 'panel',
id: 'NorthRegion',              
border:true,
title: FLang('Subsystems'),  
 appMain.WestRegion= Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {        
    region: 'west',
    xtype: 'panel',
    collapsible: true,
    floatable: true,
    width: 100,
    split: true,                
    border:true,
    title: FLang('Subsystem control'),

 }); // end of $WestRegion
 appMain.CenterRegion = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {       
region: 'center',
xtype: 'tabpanel',      
border: true,
title: FLang('Main window'),
autoScroll:true,
 });
```

Does it somehow relate to namespacing, since prior to that without namespacing there was no reference problem?

## Edits

After defining all the regions and their contents, we start app this way:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

var MainView = Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout:'border',
    border:true,
    items:[ 
        appMain.NorthRegion,
        appMain.WestRegion,
        appMain.CenterRegion   
    ], // end of viewport items      
}); 



}); // end of Ext.onReady() function
```

Comment: Nothing to do with namespacing, as long as the file is included it will be available. The code surrounding the app creation is important. When is the call to `FLang` made?

Comment: @Evan Trimboli, i added edits to show how we start app. Call to `Flang` is made in the NorthRegion config - **title: FLang('Subsystems'),** (see in application.js)

Comment: Still not enough information. When is the call to `FLang` made, in context? The `onReady` part isn't relevant because the panel is already created by that point.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli, i added code to application.js, yet i do not know when the call to `Flang` is made. How can i know it? What context?

Comment: In your `application.js` you don't show the full content. When you create the panel, is it wrapped in anything? If not, it's a simple case of load order. Your `application.js` is included and run before `lang.js`.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli, you are right. Would you form your last comment as an answer and i check it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change order of including `lang.js` and `application.js` in your index.html. However, even if it does work there is still one problem. You must not create components before the document is ready, hence, all `Ext.create` calls must be wrapped in `onReady`.

See [Ext/Touch Component Life Cycle](http://extjs.eu/ext-touch-component-life-cycle/) to learn more.